# how to multiply 2 data from registers in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I am a beginner learner of assembly. I have this problem:

I want to multiply 2 data from registers. i have this code:

```
mov ah, 0
mov al, 0002h
mov bl, 10 ;this is 10 in decimal = 0Ah in hex
mul bl
mov dx, ax
```

in my code i want to multiply `10` and `0002h` and that must be equal to `0020h`
but the result of `dx` is `dh=00 dl=14` or `0014h`.

please help...

Comment: If you use 10 in decimal (i.e. 0A in hex) then your result seems correct. 14h = 20 decimal which is what you would get from 2x10 right?

Comment: `20h == 32`. Your results are correct indeed. You either need to multiply `10h == 16` by two or expect the result to be `14h == 20`, that is, the result you correctly get right now.

Comment: yes.. indeed.. sorry i misinterpreted the value of 14h w/c is just equal to 20h.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

14h=20 decimal

To get 20h you must multiply 10h and 02h